# miniedit facility

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It would be nice if there were a possibility to edit questions or answers for misprints and other tiny changes without flushing them to the top of the list. I often notice later such blemishes of otherwise good answers or questions of mine (and others).

I therefore propose to add a miniedit button where one can make small changes to a question or answer, limited to changes of 20 characters or so, without affecting the timestamp responsible for the ordering of the questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102499/feature-request-trivial-edit-checkbox

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been discussed already in the main meta SE, and the opinion of the SE staff is that this is *not* a good idea, as it is. If questions are not bumped when edited, no one sees the edits and they cannot be reviewed by other users to check their content --- they could be incorrect, controversial, or even outright vandalism or spam.

I guess that more changes would be needed to this system to make it work --- for instance, a different system that allows these edits to be reviewed.

Comment: One could for example require enough reputation for making such edits silently,